# How to prove these inequalities ((1.23) in the book "Foundations of Time-Fequency Analysis")

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

I met the following ineualities in the book "Foundations of Time-Fequency Analysis", i.e., (1.23). How to prove them? Can someone give me a hint? Many thanks!

Given $\omega=(\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_d)\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and a positive integer $n$. There exists a constant $c>0$ such that
$$\frac{1}{c}(1+|\omega|^2)^n\le \sum_{|\alpha|\le n}|\omega^\alpha|^2\le c(1+|\omega|^2)^n,$$
where  $|\alpha|=\sum_{j=1}^d\alpha_j, \omega^\alpha=\Pi_{j=1}^d\omega_j^{\alpha_j}$ for $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_d)\in \mathbb{Z}^d_+$.

Comment: Is there a typo? There is no $\alpha$ inside the sum on the right-hand side.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks. Yes. I  just edited the summation in the middle term.

Comment: Does $\Bbb Z_+$ include $0$? (I would prefer...)

Comment: @ Anne Bauval It include 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}(1+|\omega|^2)^n&=\left(1+\sum_{j=1}^d\omega_j^2\right)^n\\&=\sum_{|\alpha|\le n}\frac{n!}{(n-|\alpha|)!\alpha_1!\dots\alpha_d!}|\omega^\alpha|^2\\&\in\left[A\sum_{|\alpha|\le n}|\omega^\alpha|^2,B\sum_{|\alpha|\le n}|\omega^\alpha|^2\right]\end{align}$$
where $A=\min_{|\alpha|\le n}\frac{n!}{(n-|\alpha|)!\alpha_1!\dots\alpha_d!}$
and $B=\max_{|\alpha|\le n}\frac{n!}{(n-|\alpha|)!\alpha_1!\dots\alpha_d!}.$

The desired inequalities are obtained for $c=\max\left(\frac1A,B\right).$

Comment: @ Anne Bauval  Thanks！But how can we get the second equality? Would you like to give the details? We should note that there is not only n terms in the summation. For example both $(1,0,\ldots,0)$ and $(0,1, 0,\ldots,0)$ and other multi-index satisfy $|\alpha|=1\le n$.

Comment: Both inequalities are proved in my answer, and include *all* terms in the summation (which are indeed more than $n$ and include indeed $|\alpha|=1$).